# Auto-resolve local URLs in comments too

Tags: feature-request, comments, hyperlinks

When **local** ELU URLs are added to question and answer fields, they are automatically resolved into question titles. For example, if I paste a random link such as this one,  [Reason for the current trend to use «she» as the gender-neutral pronoun?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28508/reason-for-the-current-trend-to-use-she-as-the-gender-neutral-pronoun) , it is displayed not as a URL, but as a linked question title.

This magic does not currently extend to comment fields. I'd like to request that it be.

Comment: Not relevant to the question, but I don't think I can really let that last sentence stand unchallenged (not that I'm going to attempt to provide a better way of putting it! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers :D I agree that it has 'dodgy' written all over it; but it appears to have largely passed muster.

Comment: haha - you mean no-one else has stepped in with a "quick fix"! I'm almost tempted to post it as a poser on main - *"What's the shortest acceptable replacement for the last three words?"*

Comment: "I'd like to request it."

Comment: @AndrewLeach The magic or the extension? :)